# JavaScript timer does not count every second

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm creating a countdown to a certain day. However, the one that I made does not seem to work for some reason. I intended it to be recalled every second by using setInterval but it only shows the time when I load the page.

Here is the code

```
// Timer
targetDate = new Date(2014, 8, 22, 0, 0, 0);

function tick(ddate, id) {

    var dateNow = new Date();
    var amount = ddate.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();
    delete dateNow;

    if (amount <= 0) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="Now!";
    } else {
        var days, hours, mins, secs, out;
        days = 0; hours = 0; mins = 0; secs = 0; out = "";

        amount = Math.floor(amount/1000);

        days = Math.floor(amount / 86400);
        amount %= 86400;

        hours = Math.floor(amount / 3600);
        amount %= 3600;

        mins = Math.floor(amount / 60);
        amount %= 60;

        secs = Math.floor(amount);

        out += "There are ";
        out += (days <= 9?'0':'') + days + " " + ((days == 1)?"day":"days") + ", ";
        out += (hours <= 9?'0':'') + hours + " " + ((hours == 1)?"hour":"hours") + ", ";
        out += (mins <= 9?'0':'') + mins + " " + ((mins == 1)?"min":"mins") + ", ";
        out += (secs <= 9?'0':'') + secs + " " + ((secs == 1)?"sec":"secs") + " ";
        out += "until the end of this semester";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = out;
    }
}

function getCount() {
    setInterval(tick(targetDate, "timer"), 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
    getCount();
};
```

Could someone please point out the part that I have messed up, thanks

Comment: There's really no reason to `delete` a local variable, and it's an error in "strict" mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `setInterval()` — you're passing the result of **calling** the function.

```
setInterval(function() { tick(targetDate, "timer"); }, 1000);
```

Your code called the function and then passed the return value (`undefined`) to `setInterval()`. Thus your code filled in the DOM element as requested, but it only did it once. The `setInterval()` call was just ignored. By instead wrapping your function call in another function, as above, the `setInterval()` will work as intended.

Be aware that the timer service is not super-accurate, and that the browser won't run your interval timer on schedule while a browser tab is not active.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling the function, not passing the function to setInterval.

setInterval accepts a function

```
setInterval(function,milliseconds)
```

The following will work:

```
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

See working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jchen86/s8zF9/

Comment: This was what I intended initially. I did not know that setInterval will accept a function without ().

Comment: Without the (), 'tick' is a reference to the function. But with (), i.e. tick(), you are actually calling/executing the function.